# how can i set mediaPlayer speed for api less then 23

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
player.setPlaybackParams(player.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(0.5f));
```

this requires an api call 23

iam trying to use SoundPool but it is not so efficent as of MediaPlayer Is any alternate to SoundPool for audioPlaying

```
final float playbackSpeed=1.5f;
                final SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

                final String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folioreader/audio"+".mp3";

                final int soundId = soundPool.load(path, 1);
                AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) mHalfSpeed.getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                final float volume = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
                    {
                        soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, playbackSpeed);
                    }
                });

                soundPool.pause(soundId)
```

Comment: Did you tried `int setPlaybackRate (int sampleRateInHz)` in `AudioTrack.class`?

Comment: how to implement it can you give a sample code

Comment: I tried audio audio track class but it gives me white sound

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Give an update on what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Use media codec class. This class can decode it and you can use Audio Track on decoded data to render (play) it. But you need to skip the samples as per your speed requirement to play in the particular speed. This approach should work. Refer mediacodec and audiotrack in android developer resources.